# What method should I use to delete tableview currently selected object for Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, protocols

What method should I use to delete the currently selected object in a table view?

The objects are put into an array and a controller is used to get the object in the array to display on the table view. But from what I can see in `NSMutableArray`s method list I cannot see a method to delete a currently selected object.

Do I need a protocol for this, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` has a method you can use. Do something like:

```
[dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Once the object is removed, you can call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

to refresh the UI.

Comment: Yea I know but can you tell me how I can delete the object selected when I'm running the program. Like when I run the program I select on of the item in the list in the tableview I want to delete it. What method should i use or what protocol should i use.

Comment: if you are using ARC, and you don't have any references to the item in the beyond what was in the array, then it will be deallocated (removed from memory) automatically by ARC. You should not need to explicitly delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The array is just a container of data, it has no concept of a selected item. The table view is just the presentation of the data, it has no concept of the underlying data, though it does understand the selection (to some extent).

It is the responsibility of your controller to bind these together. So, when the delete option is selected, it knows (or gets from the table view) the selection and deletes the item from the array.

The array supports this with the `removeObjectAtIndex:`, but your controller needs to get the index.

Comment: Yea but I've create a program that can add object into the array and use it to display at the view. Now I wanted to delete the object selected in the view when I'm running the program. What should I do then?

Comment: You mean `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ?